# Google Talk Plugin in GMail on MacBook 2,1

Tags: 10.10, sound, macbook, google-talk

I'd like to use the chat section in GMail to make phone calls. I've downloaded and installed the Google Talk plugin, and it acts like it knows what it's doing. But when I try to make calls, the internal laptop mic doesn't work at all (i.e., no one on the other end can hear me). In the GMail chat settings, I've tried selecting "Default Device" for the microphone, as well as "Internal Audio Analog Stereo." No matter which setting I try, none seem to work.

As I said at the top, this is only a problem in Ubuntu; it works just fine in OSX and Windows (which means that yes, my Google Voice account is properly configured). Here are my tech specs:

- Ubuntu 10.10
- Kernel Linux 2.6.35-24-generic
- Gnome 2.32.0
- Google Chrome 8.0.552.237
- Google Talk Plugin (google-talkplugin) 1.8.0.0-1
- MacBook (2,1) w/ internal microphone

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe there is an issue of access. Can Google Chrome access your mic input?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu natively or through a virtual machine?

Comment: Try checking the sound input preferences (System > Preferences > Sound > Input [tab]) when you try to make a call.  With Ubuntu 10.10, I had problems with my microphone volume automatically turning almost all the way down every time I tried to make a call. My parents occasionally have this problem (with 10.10) as well.

Comment: Oh, I see this is more than half a year old.  Hopefully your problems disappeared in 11.04... mine did. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have microphone problems "everywhere", or is it limited to the gtalk plugin?

Also, did you make sure that your microphone isn't muted?

Comment: Good question. No, I don't have mic problems elsewhere. For instance, I just did a test recording in Audacity and it worked just fine (and isn't muted).